# Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (unplugged) - NVidia GTX 970

Tags: nvidia, sound, 15.10, hdmi

I have a problem with audio through HDMI. My display is connected via HDMI cable but Audio doesn't work. HDMI audio output is not visible in default ubuntu sound settings. After installation of `pavucontrol` in configuration tab all outputs assigned to nvidia sound driver are visible as unplugged. Is there any option to "plug" this audio outputs.

Till now i tried to:

- upgrade NVidia drivers (currently running 361.28)
- install daily alsa drivers (`oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms` from ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily repo)
- uninstall/reinstall pulseaudio
- distro-upgrade
- play with xorg.conf file
- enable everything in alsamixer
- use different HDMI cable (unfortunately i have no access to other receiver)
- enable static load of `hw:1,3` device in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- multiple `xrandr` commands with switching modes turning on/off setting to auto and setting audio to on

I moved from Windows and there HDMI sound worked fine.

Bellow some links which maybe provide more information.

[pavucontrol config tab (all other outputs have unplugged value as well)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stpl9.png)

[alsa-info.sh](http://pastebin.com/cy1u2zSW)

/proc/asound listing (all eld files have eld_valid = 0)

```
/proc/asound$ cat cards 
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7330000 irq 38
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 17
/proc/asound$ cat NVidia/eld#0.*
monitor_present     0
eld_valid       0
monitor_present     0
eld_valid       0
monitor_present     0
eld_valid       0
monitor_present     0
eld_valid       0e here
```

xrandr --verbose

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1be
    Timestamp:  977600
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: VGA 
        supported: VGA
    ConnectorType: DVI-I 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1bf
    Timestamp:  977600
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DVI-I 
    ConnectorNumber: 0 
    _ConnectorLocation: 0 
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x1c3) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x1c0
    Timestamp:  977600
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: HDMI 
    ConnectorNumber: 2 
    _ConnectorLocation: 2 
  1024x768 (0x1c1) 78.750MHz +HSync +VSync +preferred
        h: width  1024 start 1040 end 1136 total 1312 skew    0 clock  60.02KHz
        v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  800           clock  75.03Hz
  1920x1200 (0x1c2) 154.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1203 end 1209 total 1235           clock  59.95Hz
  1920x1080 (0x1c3) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
  1792x1344 (0x1c4) 204.800MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1792 start 1920 end 2120 total 2448 skew    0 clock  83.66KHz
        v: height 1344 start 1345 end 1348 total 1394           clock  60.01Hz
  1680x1050 (0x1c5) 187.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1800 end 1976 total 2272 skew    0 clock  82.31KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1099           clock  74.89Hz
  1680x1050 (0x1c6) 174.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1800 end 1976 total 2272 skew    0 clock  76.58KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1096           clock  69.88Hz
  1680x1050 (0x1c7) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1680x1050 (0x1c8) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
  1600x1200 (0x1c9) 175.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  81.25KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  65.00Hz
  1600x1200 (0x1ca) 162.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1600 start 1664 end 1856 total 2160 skew    0 clock  75.00KHz
        v: height 1200 start 1201 end 1204 total 1250           clock  60.00Hz
  1440x900 (0x1cb) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1400x1050 (0x1cc) 155.800MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1464 end 1784 total 1912 skew    0 clock  81.49KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1090           clock  74.76Hz
  1400x1050 (0x1cd) 145.060MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1496 end 1648 total 1896 skew    0 clock  76.51KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1051 end 1054 total 1093           clock  70.00Hz
  1400x1050 (0x1ce) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz
  1360x768 (0x1cf) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
  1360x768 (0x1d0) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1d1) 135.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1296 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  79.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  75.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1d2) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x960 (0x1d3) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
        v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x1d4) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x1d5) 104.990MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1224 end 1352 total 1552 skew    0 clock  67.65KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  902           clock  75.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x1d6) 96.770MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1224 end 1344 total 1536 skew    0 clock  63.00KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  70.00Hz
  1152x864 (0x1d7) 81.620MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x1d8) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
  1024x768 (0x1d9) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  960x600 (0x1da) 77.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  74.04KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  617           clock  60.00Hz
  960x540 (0x1db) 69.250MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   960 start  984 end 1000 total 1040 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
        v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  555           clock  59.99Hz
  840x525 (0x1dc) 93.500MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  900 end  988 total 1136 skew    0 clock  82.31KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  549           clock  74.96Hz
  840x525 (0x1dd) 87.000MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  900 end  988 total 1136 skew    0 clock  76.58KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  548           clock  69.88Hz
  840x525 (0x1de) 73.125MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  892 end  980 total 1120 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  544           clock  60.01Hz
  840x525 (0x1df) 59.500MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   840 start  864 end  880 total  920 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  529 total  540           clock  59.88Hz
  832x624 (0x1e0) 57.284MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   832 start  864 end  928 total 1152 skew    0 clock  49.73KHz
        v: height  624 start  625 end  628 total  667           clock  74.55Hz
  800x600 (0x1e1) 49.500MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  816 end  896 total 1056 skew    0 clock  46.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  604 total  625           clock  75.00Hz
  800x600 (0x1e2) 50.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  976 total 1040 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  600 start  637 end  643 total  666           clock  72.19Hz
  800x600 (0x1e3) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x1e4) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  720x450 (0x1e5) 53.250MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   720 start  760 end  836 total  952 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  450 start  451 end  454 total  467           clock  59.89Hz
  700x525 (0x1e6) 77.900MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  732 end  892 total  956 skew    0 clock  81.49KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  545           clock  74.76Hz
  700x525 (0x1e7) 61.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   700 start  744 end  820 total  940 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
        v: height  525 start  526 end  532 total  541           clock  59.98Hz
  680x384 (0x1e8) 36.000MHz +HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  704 end  720 total  760 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  395           clock  59.96Hz
  680x384 (0x1e9) 42.375MHz -HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   680 start  716 end  784 total  888 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  390 total  399           clock  59.80Hz
  640x480 (0x1ea) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  720 total  840 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
        v: height  480 start  481 end  484 total  500           clock  75.00Hz
  640x480 (0x1eb) 31.500MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  664 end  704 total  832 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  480 start  489 end  492 total  520           clock  72.81Hz
  640x480 (0x1ec) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  512x384 (0x1ed) 37.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  664 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  70.07Hz
  512x384 (0x1ee) 32.500MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   512 start  524 end  592 total  672 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  384 start  385 end  388 total  403           clock  60.00Hz
  400x300 (0x1ef) 25.000MHz +HSync +VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   400 start  428 end  488 total  520 skew    0 clock  48.08KHz
        v: height  300 start  318 end  321 total  333           clock  72.19Hz
  320x240 (0x1f0) 15.750MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  332 end  352 total  416 skew    0 clock  37.86KHz
        v: height  240 start  244 end  246 total  260           clock  72.81Hz
  320x240 (0x1f1) 12.587MHz -HSync -VSync DoubleScan
        h: width   320 start  328 end  376 total  400 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  240 start  245 end  246 total  262           clock  60.05Hz
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1f2
    Timestamp:  977600
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: DisplayPort 
        supported: DisplayPort
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 3 
    _ConnectorLocation: 3 
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1f3
    Timestamp:  977600
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DisplayPort 
    ConnectorNumber: 3 
    _ConnectorLocation: 3 
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x1f4
    Timestamp:  977600
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: DVI-D 
    ConnectorNumber: 1 
    _ConnectorLocation: 1
```

Comment: In the terminal, what is the output from: `setpci -vD -s 01:00.0 0x488.l=0x2000000:0x2000000`